# How to add Spring Initializr support to IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

How can I use **Spring Initializr** support in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020?
IntelliJ documentation recommend me:

```
Create a Spring Boot project﻿
From the main menu, select File | New | Project.

In the left pane of the New Project wizard, select Spring Initializr.
```

But I have no such point in Project Wizard.
Other topics here recommend to enable or install plugin.
But I have no such plugin in installed and also have no such plugin in marketplace.
I found only SpringBootGen plugin but it not help me, still no any new point in Project Wizard panel and no any information how to use it.
Please help!

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18622-spring-initializr-and-assistant There is a recent plug in added to Intellij plugin section. try above.

Answer (score 3):

Spring is supported in Ultimate Edition only: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Comment: Is any 3-d part plugin to use?

Comment: I guess you may use online version: https://start.spring.io/

Answer (score 1):

There is a plug-in called: "Spring Intilializr and Assistent" - go to Settings or Preferences (depending on OS) - there PlugIns -> Marketplace, search for it and install.

So no need for the Ultimate version …
It basically uses the website [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io) (or you can use a custom one, don't know how this works exactly) to get the files, but more convenient.